# Deploy firebase cloud function with default user

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-functions

I have created some cloud functions. I have functions that rely on a custom claim that has admin as a role. I want to be able to create a default user (set in an environment variable) to have admin role so it can be used to assign others if needed but can only be created during deployment. Is that possible to put in cloud functions so it creates a user when deploying the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible to put in cloud functions so it creates a user when deploying the functions?

No.  Any accounts required for deployment must exist prior to deployment.  Whatever command you're running (gcloud or firebase CLI) can't double up work in a single command.  You would need to run at least two commands to get everything set up, or create your own program or script that does all the work in one shot.

Comment: So what would be the best practice, create an admin account manually before deployment? My idea is to prevent any one person from creating an admin, even if it is an employee/developer.